# trigger css keyframe animation with alpine js

Tags: css, alpine.js

I'd like to create an animation that fades an element out and then back in again on click of a button with alpine and css keyframe animations.

my html/alpine

```
<div x-data="{ anim: true }">
      <button x-on:click="anim = ! anim">fade box</button>
      <div :class="anim ? '' : 'fade-out-in'" class="w-32 h-32 relative bg-lead">
      </div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
  .fade-out-in{
    -webkit-animation: fade-out-in 5s;
    animation: fade-out-in 5s;
  }

  @keyframes fade-out-in {
    0%   { opacity: 1;}
    50%  {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
  }
```

This almost works except there is a problem with the logic of toggling the class name. What ends up happening is every second click I'm removing the `fade-out-in` class and so nothing happens until the following click where the class gets added again.

I'm not sure what a smarter way to approach this would be, one thought is I coud have two classes that do the same thing and they alternately get toggled so there is an animation on every click... but that seems clunky, there must be a way where I don't have to toggle the class at all I would think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the length of the animation, you can schedule a function that resets the state of the `anim`. Apply the [`throttle` modifier](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#throttle) to prevent multiple clicks.

```css
  .fade-out-in{
    -webkit-animation: fade-out-in 5s;
    animation: fade-out-in 5s;
  }

  @keyframes fade-out-in {
    0%   { opacity: 1;}
    50%  {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ anim: false }">
      <button @click.throttle.5000ms="anim = true; setTimeout(() => {anim = false},5000)">fade box</button>
      <div :class="anim && 'fade-out-in'" class="w-32 h-32 relative bg-lead" style="width: 220px; border: 3px solid salmon; padding: 5px; margin: 10px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      <div x-text="`Animation state: ${anim}`"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great! I had thought of setTimeout but it was getting messed up on multiple clicks, thanks for the throttle modifier suggestion I wasn't really aware of that one.